# Mongoose remove in async.parallel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-async

I don't quite understand, why this doesn't work:

```
async.parallel([
  SomeStuff.find({}).remove,
  SomeStuff2.find({}).remove,
  SomeStuff3.find({}).remove
], done);
```

while this works ok

```
async.parallel([
  function(callback) {
    SomeStuff.find({}).remove(callback)
  },
  function(callback) {
    SomeStuff2.find({}).remove(callback);
  },
  function(callback) {
    SomeStuff3.find({}).remove(callback);
  }
], done);
```

Isn't it practically the same? 
The first one throws an error:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'cast'
at Query.remove (/path/to/project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1366:10)
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `.remove` is not bound to a context - it's just a function at that point I think.  You could do Query.remove.bind(SomeStuff.find({})) I think, but ugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're losing the function context when you pass the function itself like that. `remove()` is a prototype method, so it relies on the value of `this` being correct. When you pass the method by itself, the `this` value is now lost so it can no longer do things like `this.cast()`.

Comment: Yes I got it, thank you!
To achieve what I wanted I can use lodash bind:
    `var query1 = SomeStuff.find({});`
    `var query2 = SomeStuff2.find({});`
    `var query3 = SomeStuff3.find({});`
    `async.parallel([`
       `_.bind(query1.remove, query1),`
       `_.bind(query2.remove, query2),`
      `_.bind(query3.remove, query3),`
    `], done);`